# Programatically added Fragment to FrameLayout is not shown after orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments

1. I have an `Activity` that holds one `Fragment`.
2. In this fragment (that has `RelativeLayout` set as content view) I add programmatically many `FrameLayouts`.
3. During adding I set id for those framelayouts using `View.generateId()`.
4. Then I add programmatically nested fragments to those `FrameLayouts` (let's call them *Slots*).
5. Finally I add again nested fragments but this time to *slots*. And in *slots* I can add `MyImageFragment`, `MyVideoFragment`, `MyWebViewFragment`.
6. Using `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` I change content of *slots*

The problem I encounter is that when I rotate my device I do not see my fragments that I add.

I reuse my fragments using `findFragmentByTag()`.

Hierarchy before rotation:

[image: before rotation]

and after rotation:

[image: after rotation]

How to resolve that problem? Why fragments are not attached?

Comment: add setRetainInstance( boolean ); in your fragments onActivityCreated();

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that on the lowest level (*slot* level) I did not save the value that was generated by `View.generateId()`. So I needed to add this part of code.

```
public static String LAYOUT_ID = "LAYOUT_ID";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        frameLayoutId = savedInstanceState.getInt(LAYOUT_ID);
    } else {
        frameLayoutId = -1;
    }
 }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slot, container, false);

    if (frameLayoutId == -1)
        frameLayoutId = View.generateViewId() ;

    view.setId(frameLayoutId);
    }

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt(LAYOUT_ID, frameLayoutId);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```